# How do I remap my CAPS Lock key to Hyper?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 16.10, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I tried [this guy's solution](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2017/02/09/a-new-range-of-shortcuts-with-the-hyper-key/), but I got the following error:

```
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request: 118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
Value in failed request: 0x17
Serial number of failed request: 16
Current serial number in output stream: 16
```

Basically, I'm shooting for a new "namespace" of hotkeys where I can be reasonably certain to have no conflicts.

Comment: To avoid several levels of indirection, the solution referred to seems to be [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/capslock-as-modifier-key-for-application-keymaps/151046#151046).